# Which cocoapods version to use on Mac 10.12, If Restkit is the dependency

Tags: ios, cocoapods, restkit, macos-sierra

I was using **0.37.2** pod version on previous mac version. Its not working on Sierra. If i upgrade the pods, Restkit creates an issue for File not found. Tried all the possible answers to make Restkit work on new pod version but no success. If someone else got the same issue, what is the fix?

> [!] Unable to load a specification for the plugin `/Users/q/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/gems/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.1`
>   Analyzing dependencies
>   [!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.37.2)
>   Update CocoaPods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/

using old specs worked.

> For people who want to continue using 0.x versions, we will be
>   replicating the Specs repo from the commit before the repo was
>   sharded. This means you can add:
>
> source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"
>
> To the top of your Podfile, and CocoaPods will only use the archived
>   repo, instead of using the new repo structure. You will also need to
>   set your local Specs repo to a version before the transition:
>
> cd ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/ git fetch origin master git checkout
>   v0.32.1